# String class using linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I have to write this String class which is represented using linked list. I seem to have problems with my copy constructor and I have no idea how to write my assignment operator. Any idea where the mistake is and how to write them? The shown code is for the copy constructor with the following operation String s="word". I'm not sure how to write one for String s1=s2. Here is my code so far:

---

```
struct Element
{
char data;
Element* next;
};
class String
{
   Element* top;
public:
   String();
   bool empty() const;
   char last() const;
   char pop();
   void push(char);
   friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const String&);
   friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, String&);
   String(const char*);
};

String::String(const char *p)
{
    int l = strlen(p);
    for(int i=0; i < l+1 ; i++)
    {
        Element *newElement;
        newElement = new Element;
        newElement->data = p[i];
        newElement->next = NULL;
        if(top == NULL)
        {
            top = newElement;
        }
        else
        {
            Element *tmp = top;
            while(tmp->next != NULL)
            {
                tmp = tmp->next;
                tmp->next = newElement;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
String s="Hello";
std::cout<<s;//operator<< works tested it
}
```

Comment: Including what error you are seeing and what you have done to troubleshoot the problem would be useful.

Comment: @brader24 I don't get an error but the program crashes.

Comment: @user3144334 - `I don't get an error but the program crashes`  You didn't post a program -- you just posted a class.  A class doesn't live without something giving it life.  Please post a main() function that duplicates the error.

Comment: what type is newElement->data ? your while loop looks wrong too, you assign newElement to every Element instance in the list.

Comment: @user3144334 - Please post the `Element` class.  Also, there is no copy constructor in the code you posted.  Where is the `String(const String&)` function?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I haven't wrote it yet because I'm not sure how to make the deep copying.

Comment: Have you stepped through with the debugger and identified the point at which it crashes and why?  Are you trying to access a value that is null?  Trying to write beyond the bounds of an array?

Answer (score 1):

If you defined single-linked list when it is much better to add new elements at the head of the list instead of the tail. Nevertheless your function could look the following way

```
String::String(const char*p)
{
   for ( ; *p; ++p )
   {
      Element *newElement = new Element;
      newElement->data = *p;
      newElement->next = NULL;

      if ( top == NULL )
      {
         top = newElement;
      }
      else
      {
         Element *tmp = top;

         while ( tmp->next != NULL ) temp = tmp->next;

         tmp->next = newElement;
      }
   }
}
```

By the way it is not a copy constructor. As for the copy constructor then it could be defined as

```
String::String( const String &s ) : top( NULL )
{
   if ( s.top )
   {
      top = new Element;
      top->data = s.top->data;
      top->next = NULL;

      for ( Element *tmp1 = top, tmp2 = s.top; tmp2->next; tmp1 = tmp1->next, tmp2 = tmp2->next )
      {
         tmp1->next = new Element;
         tmp1->next->data = tmp2->next->data;
         tmp1->next->next = NULL;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, your `while` loop will never execute since the `top->next` will be `NULL`.

```cpp
Element *tmp = top;
while(tmp->next != NULL)
{
    ...
}
```

Also, as @Claptrap commented, you assign `newElement` on every loop iteration.

Given all of this, I'm not seeing why it would fail, but it may be in code that you have not posted.  Please try to reduce your code to the minimum necessary that reproduces the problem and then include that code in your post.